terraform cloudwatch loggroups are not creating by deafault
I am trying to create firehose delivery stream.. i am seeing one strange issue that after creation of streams i am expecting that cloudwatch log groups will be auto created but that is not happening.
Strange thing is that i can see cloudwatch log groups getting created if i create stream manually..
Another scenario i tried to do is to send some demo data in stream then i can see stream is creating..
resource "aws_iam_policy" "firehose" {
  name = "firehose-policy-${var.env_name}"
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect = "Allow"
        Action = [
          "redshift:*",
          "s3:*",
          "sqs:*",
          "cloudwatch:*",
          "cloudwatchlogs:*"
        ]
        Resource = "*"
      }
    ]
  })
}

this is my policy..
this is my stream configuration
redshift_configuration {
    role_arn        = "arn:aws:iam::${local.account_id}:role/firehose_delivery_role"
    cluster_jdbcurl = var.redshift_configurations[var.environment].redshift
    username        = var.redshift_configurations[var.environment].username
    password        = var.password
    data_table_name = var.data_table_name[count.index]
    copy_options    = "TIMEFORMAT AS 'epochmillisecs' json 'auto'"
    s3_backup_mode  = "Disabled"
    s3_configuration {
      role_arn           = "arn:aws:iam::${local.account_id}:role/firehose_delivery_role"
      bucket_arn         = "arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket_arn}"
      buffering_size     = 5
      buffering_interval = 300
      prefix             = var.prefix[count.index]
    }
    cloudwatch_logging_options {
      enabled         = true
      log_group_name  = "/aws/kinesisfirehose/${var.kinesis_redshift_name[count.index]}"
      log_stream_name = var.kinesis_redshift_name[count.index]
    }
  }

